# Switch to getJSON from raw data

Tags: json, getjson

I have this code that works for me:

```
        $('#demo').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
            var data, template, html;

            data = {
"sver": [{"title":"Buffet Stagaljxxs" , "url_titler":"buffet-stagalj" },{"title":"Restoran Vrske" , "url_titler":"restoran-vrske" }]
};

            template = '<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="false">{{#sver}}<li data-theme="b"><a href="#{{url_titler}}" data-transition="slide"><h3>{{title}}</h3><p>Opis: {{title}}</p></a></li>{{/sver}}</ul>';
            html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

            $('#content').html(html);
        });
```

Now i need to use remote json using getJSON, instead raw json like in my example.
I can't get it to work. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not the issue.

This is the [remote json address](http://wmd.hr/mobile-rss/jason/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the data by using Ajax (like the function below)

```
<script>
function getJSONData(url)
{
    var data = null;
    var request = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : (window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : null);

    if (null != request)
    {
        request.open('GET', url, false);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.send(data);

        //Parse returned JSON string.
        data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    }

     return data;
}

$('#demo').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
    var data, template, html;

    data = getJSONData('http://wmd.hr/mobile-rss/jason/');

    template = '<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="false">{{#sver}}<li data-theme="b"><a href="#{{url_titler}}" data-transition="slide"><h3>{{title}}</h3><p>Opis: {{title}}</p></a></li>{{/sver}}</ul>';
    html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

    $('#content').html(html);
});
</script>
```

Comment: That did not work.
I created a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fcRgN/2/
Maybe you can work it out.

Comment: I am not familiar with JQuery but I did realize that I missed the *JSON.parse* function.  I went ahead and edited my answer and changed it to *data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);*  I played with the Fiddle and cannot get it to run the lambda function that is being created on *pagecreate* but I tested the *getJSONData* function and it did work.  How does *$('#demo').live('pagecreate', function(event) {* execute the function?

Comment: @user2239570 There is also [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function which asynchronously retrieves the value too.